# How to delete git-notes commit?

Tags: git

`git-notes` is used to add or inspect object notes. How can I delete a `git-notes` commit, so the commit of git-notes command will not exist in git history. I want to delete git-notes commit, I'm not mean the "git-notes remove", which only remove that notes and make another commit.

Comment: Please refer to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18507031

Comment: @Igor IMO that doesn’t answer the question. It seems that OP wants to delete a specific commit created by git-notes(1). As in: similar to removing a commit with git-rebase(1).

Answer (score 13):

As git stores notes on a non-branch ref (pointed by `refs/notes/commits` by default), you can create a branch, pointing at notes head, edit it as usual (using `rebase`, for example), and update notes reference to the tip of that branch:

```
// create branch pointing to the tip of notes branch
git checkout -B notes-editing refs/notes/commits

// do whatever you want with notes-editing branch
// for example, git reset --hard HEAD^ to remove last commit

// reset notes reference to the tip of temporary branch
git update-ref refs/notes/commits notes-editing
// remove temporary branch
git checkout master
git branch -D notes-editing
```

To completely remove the notes (from the current repo), you need to delete the `notes/commits` reference, but removing the file might not be sufficient, better to do it properly:

```
git update-ref -d refs/notes/commits
```

Comment: the last step: `git branch -D` does not delete `git notes` commits as the usual branch.

Comment: You want to remove all notes completely? Then you should just remove `.git/refs/notes/commits` file.

Comment: @max I think removing `.git/refs/notes/commits` would only remove the (local) reference to the notes, but not the actual note objects

Comment: if there is only one note (one commit) and we want to remove it, git reset HEAD^ returns "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree"

Comment: The only solution that worked for me was removing `.git/refs/notes/commits` as @max points out and then run `git gc`

Comment: Removing `.git/refs/notes/commits` manually does not work if the notes refs has already been packed. I had to use `git update-ref -d refs/notes/commits` followed by `git gc --prune=all --aggressive`.

Answer (score 2):

`git notes prune` Removes all notes for non-existing/unreachable objects.

Answer (score -3):

`git notes` does not create an own commit.

It could actually be used to add (`git notes add`) some notes to an existing commit.

When you call `git notes remove`, the notes are removed and again no own commit is made.

Comment: `git notes` does not create an own commit, however, it will be shown in history(`git log --all`). Is there any way to delete `git notes`, so that it will not be shown in history. Thank you!

Comment: Sure it (like `git notes edit`) creates commits. Just try to browse the commits with e.g. `git log refs/notes/commit`.