# git: How to delete a local ref branch?

Tags: git, git-notes

I have bit of a difficulty in deleting a local ref branch(refs/notes/origin/commits).
I was able to delete the branch(refs/notes/origin/commits) in the remote repository using the command

```
git push origin :refs/notes/origin/commits
```

but when i try to delete the same branch on my local repository, i get the below error

```
[User@centos Clone]# git branch -rd refs/notes/origin/commits
error: remote branch 'refs/notes/origin/commits' not found.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Just do

```
git branch -d commits
```

to delete the local branch.

Use the `-D` switch to delete it irrespective of its merged status.

Use

```
git update-ref -d refs/notes/origin/commits
```

to delete the ref.

You can also hard-delete it as mentioned in other answers with

```
rm -rf .git/refs/notes
```

Comment: This was also helpful to fix an error message `error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature-x': is at [Guid1] but expected [Guid2]`

Comment: This was perfect for removing an improperly tagged commit I made locally. These are in `refs/tags/`.

Comment: Out of your suggestions, `git update-ref -d refs/notes/origin/commits` is what I was looking for.

Comment: The hard-delete did not work for me but the `git update-ref -d` did. Thanks :)

Comment: For me, I had to delete a bad remote branch ref locally (`git branch -r` branches). My prefix on the branch was a bit different. Had to run `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/<Remote-Branch-Name>` where in my case `<Remote-Branch-Name>` was `origin/feature/page-visit`

Answer (score 7):

You have notes in your git repository, you can delete one note with

```
git notes remove <commit>
```

or you can use the git update-ref command.

```
git update-ref -d refs/notes/commits
```

You can also use the `rm` command to accomplish this goal, but you should not use it. Git is a very complex tool that stores management data and knows best how to manage it, only if you use this tool suite you can be sure not to end up in an inconsistent state.

For deleting of all notes, you have to remove the 'notes' directory

```
rm -rf .git/refs/notes
```

Comment: What would be the upside of using `rm -rf <dir>` over `update-ref`? Do you sometimes need to use `rm -rf` because you can’t use the latter command?

Comment: No, I don't think there will be a situation where the git command `git update-ref` can't be used. **And you should always use it.** This git command does a few other things too, such as updating "administrative data" like the `.git/packed-refs` file. (Please read the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git-pack-refs.1.html)  to find out what this command/file does).

I'm, adapting my answer to point out `rm` should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

you can just delete the file out of the .git directory. From the repository root, a command like this will get it:

```
rm .git/refs/tags/refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

The path may be slightly different if the git-tag command failed, so you may want to         cd .git/refs and find the offending head by trial-and-error. Deleting the file will remove the reference from your local repository.