# How can I delete the current Git branch?

Tags: git

I have a branch called `Test_Branch`. When I try to delete it using the recommend method, I get the following error:

> Cannot delete branch 'Test_Branch' checked out at '[directory
> location]'.

I get no other information besides that. I can blow away the remote branch easy but the local branch won't go away.

Comment: If you execute `git branch`, what does it say?

Comment: In picture, this is what is happening: http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/velka/1210-1240955295Hn8Q.jpg

Comment: git branch gives me 
*Test_Branch
master

Comment: The star tells you which branch you are currently in, this confirms what the answers say

Comment: Tutorial https://makandracards.com/makandra/621-git-delete-a-branch-local-or-remote can help you in this problem

Comment: renaming the branch and then deleting it helped me.

Answer (score 495, accepted):

Switch to some other branch and delete `Test_Branch`, as follows:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch -d Test_Branch
```

If above command gives you error - `The branch 'Test_Branch' is not fully merged. If you are sure you want to delete it` and still you want to delete it, then you can **force delete it using `-D` instead of `-d`**, as:

```
$ git branch -D Test_Branch
```

To delete `Test_Branch` from remote as well, execute:

```
git push origin --delete Test_Branch
```

Comment: **Switching branches** was what got me - good catch! You can't delete the branch if you are active in it. ;-)

Comment: If you try a few different checkouts and still get the same message, look at the output of `git status`, or `git branch`; if you are rebasing Test_branch then simply checking out a different branch/commit will not fix this. Instead `git rebase --abort` then `git checkout --detach` and finally `git branch -D Test_branch`

Comment: Further evidence that **git** stands for **"git is terrible".**  The more I use it the more of these ridiculous hoops you have to jump through.  Especially since you probably want to switch right back to the same branch.

Comment: And what if someone gets this in return, when trying to change branches? `error: you need to resolve your current index first` and they just want to LEAVE? EDIT - Solution: `git reset --`; `git checkout -D [branch_name]` Phew..

Comment: Had to do run `git fetch --prune` because I had already deleted the branch on remote but it was still showing up after `git pull` in `git branch -a`.

Comment: `git checkout -b main` write `-b` flag for creating a new branch.

Answer (score 48):

I had a similar problem except that the bad branch was in the middle of rebase.
`git checkout bad_branch && git rebase --abort` solved my issue.

Comment: Force delete didn't work for me, as corruption in rebase was the reason. This solution worked. +1.

Comment: This works for me. If you tried to merge other_branch to the bad_branch before and you forgot it, it will say you have checked out the bad_branch even if you are not. After abort the merge process, the bad_branch can be deleted by -d or -D.

Comment: Thanks!  My IDE said a rebase was in progress on a completely unrelated branch, which is what lead me to this answer.  `git` didn't (obviously?) seem to mind, which is what made the problem even harder to track down/understand.

Answer (score 36):

Ran into this today and switching to another branch didn't help. It turned out that somehow my worktree information had gotten corrupted and there was a worktree with the same folder path as my working directory with a `HEAD` pointing at the branch (`git worktree list`). I deleted the `.git/worktree/` folder that was referencing it and `git branch -d` worked.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer in my opinion, because when I encountered the error the simple `git branch -D` solution did not work for me - the error was persistent.

Answer (score 26):

You probably have Test_Branch checked out, and you may not delete it while it is your current branch.  Check out a different branch, and then try deleting Test_Branch.

Answer (score 18):

If you have created multiple worktrees with [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), you'll need to run `git worktree prune` before you can delete the branch

Comment: more specifically, you will need to use `git worktree prune`

Comment: but read what git prune does, first - could lead to data loss

Comment: Rather than using `git worktree prune`, I would suggest using `git worktree remove <worktree>`  to be sure that you do not delete more work-tree information than you need to.
If you have doubts, read the documentation that is output from this command: `git help worktree`

Answer (score 14):

If any of the other answers did not work for you,
this can also happen if you are in the middle of a rebase.
So either finish the rebase or abort it:

```
git rebase --abort
```

Afterward, you can remove the branch.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had a bisect I guess I didn't reset. Switching to the offending branch, running `git bisect reset`, and then switching to a different branch allowed the offending branch to then be deleted.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

In my case there were uncommitted changes from the previous branch lingering around. I used following commands and then delete worked.

```
git checkout *    
git checkout master
git branch -D <branch name>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you run into this problem where you have checkedout and not able to delete the branch and getting this error message

"error: Cannot delete branch 'issue-123' checked out at ....."

Then check the branch you are currently in by using
git branch

If the branch you are trying to delete is your current branch, you cannot delete the same. Just switch to the main or master or any other branch and then try deleting

git checkout main or master

git branch -d branchname
git branch -D branchname
git branch -D branchname --force

Answer (score 4):

Most junior programmers that faced

`Cannot delete branch 'my-branch-name'`

Because they are already on that branch.

It's not logical to delete the branch that you are already working on it.

Just switch to another branch like `master` or `dev` and after that delete the branch that you want:

`git checkout dev`

`git branch -d my-branch-name`

without `force delete`, you can delete that branch

Comment: Most junior programmers make better error messages than "Cannot delete branch"

Comment: Though to be fair - the message is "Cannot delete branch ... checked out at ...". "checked out" is the proper way to describe "being on that branch"

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me...

I have removed the folders there in .git/worktrees folder and then tried "git delete -D branch-name".

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this problem today for branches reported by `git branch -a` and look like this one: `remotes/coolsnake/dev`, i.e. a local references to "remote" branches in registered `git remote add ...` remotes.

When you try

```
git branch -d remotes/coolsnake/dev
```

you'll get the `error: branch 'remotes/coolsnake/dev' not found`.

The magic is to remember here that these are references and MUST be deleted via

```
git update-ref -d remotes/coolsnake/dev
```

(as per https://superuser.com/questions/283309/how-to-delete-the-git-reference-refs-original-refs-heads-master/351085#351085)

Took a while to uncover my mistake and only the fact that TortoiseGit could do it led me on the right path when I was stuck. Google DID NOT deliver anything useful despite several different approaches. (No that I've found what I needed there's also [git: How to delete a local ref branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506456/git-how-to-delete-a-local-ref-branch), which did NOT show up as I had forgotten the 'ref' bit about these branches being *references*.)

Hope this helps someone else to get unstuck when they're in the same boat as me, trying to filter/selectively remove branches in a repo where some of them are present due to previous `git remote add` commands.

---

In a shell script this then might look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# Remove GNU/cesanta branches so we cannot accidentally merge or cherrypick from them!
# 

# commit hash is first GNU commit
R=218428662e6f8d30a83cf8a89f531553f1156d25

for f in $( git tag -l ; git branch -a ) ; do 
    echo "$f"
    X=$(git merge-base $R "$f" ) 
    #echo "X=[$X]" 
    if test "$X" = "$R" ; then 
        echo GNU 
        git branch -D "$f" 
        git update-ref -d "refs/$f" 
        git tag -d "$f" 
        #git push origin --delete "$f" 
    else 
        echo CIVETWEB 
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

ran into same problem,
checked out to different branch and used `git branch -D branch_name`
worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Like others mentioned you cannot delete current branch in which you are working.

In my case, I have selected "Test_Branch" in **Visual Studio** and was trying to delete "Test_Branch" from Sourcetree (Git GUI). And was getting below error message.

> Cannot delete branch 'Test_Branch' checked out at '[directory
>   location]'.

Switched to different branch in **Visual Studio** and was able to delete "Test_Branch" from Sourcetree.

I hope this helps someone who is using **Visual Studio** & **Sourcetree**.

Answer (score 1):

[badambassador](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5213219/badambassador)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75524794/6309) mentions the case of a [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) in-progress in a worktree.

One reason a `git bisect` can remain incomplete is because it remains stuck on a commit needing to check out a branch in a worktree... while that same branch is *also* checked out in another worktree.

To avoid that scenario, you can use a new option with Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), which allows "[`git bisect reset`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c79786c486cb84e2f9dad41a04d982bb23075815/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_reset))</sup> to check out the original branch when the branch is already checked out in a different worktree linked to the same repository.

See [commit 7fb8904](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fb89047cc3957bf829233786c00edd5d87f0225) (22 Jan 2023) by [Rubén Justo (`rjusto`)](https://github.com/rjusto).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c79786c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c79786c486cb84e2f9dad41a04d982bb23075815), 19 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fb89047cc3957bf829233786c00edd5d87f0225): fix "`reset`" when branch is checked out elsewhere
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rubén Justo</sup>

> Since [1d0fa89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d0fa898eaa879d2fa4785164c3261dd40fe5f89) ("`checkout`: add `--ignore-other-wortrees`", 2015-01-03, Git v2.5.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68a2e6a2c80303144807c8c91a087427e3c8e727) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22aca1b3ac10af7188dccf033b44a36926f04d4b)) we have a safety valve in checkout/switch to prevent the same branch from being checked out simultaneously in multiple worktrees.
>
> If a branch is bisected in a worktree while also being checked out in another worktree; when the bisection is finished, checking out the branch back in the current worktree may fail.
>
> Let's teach bisect to use the "`--ignore-other-worktrees`" flag.

So you can now do a `git bisect reset --ignore-other-worktrees` (to clean up the current bisect), and then change branches to allow the deletion of the current branch in the main repository.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to checkout other branch

```
git chekcout master
```

and then delete the required branch

```
git branch -d Test_Branch
```

Answer (score 0):

//first checkout to other branch

```
git checkout master
```

// delete branch locally

```
git branch -d localBranchName
```

// delete branch remotely

```
git push origin --delete remoteBranchName
```

// refresh branch list

```
git fetch -p
```

Answer (score 0):

run `git worktree prune` before you can delete the branch, if you have created multiple worktrees

Answer (score -2):

```
git branch --D branch-name
```

Please run this code to delete